# High-pitched noise when USB mouse receiver is plugged in and CPU is idle

Tags: usb, mouse, noise

When my wireless USB mouse receiver is plugged into my laptop, my laptop generates a high-pitched hissing noise that's very irritating -- but only if the CPU is idling. (It goes away when there is CPU activity.)

What's the best way (if any) of getting rid of the noise?

Comment: Is your cellphone near the usb device?

Comment: Can you tell where the noise is coming from? Is it coming from the speakers?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's really hard to tell... it seems to be louder on the bottom side of the laptop than the top, so it probably isn't the speakers, but I'm really not sure. (I checked that it isn't the batteries, though, by taking them out.)

Comment: Similar: http://superuser.com/questions/121883/any-way-to-disable-specific-cpu-idle-cx-states

Comment: Also similar (except this one happens even on AC power with no battery): http://superuser.com/questions/373679/cpu-whine-with-usb-mouse-inserted-while-on-battery